python windows subprocess.run() keep raising filenotfound exception
def _dbpath(self) -> Path:
    filepath = Path(__file__).parent.parent.joinpath('postgres')
    return filepath

try:
    command = [
        'pg_restore',
        '-h localhost',
        f'-U {_DBUSER}',
        f'-d {_DBNAME}',
        f'-p {_DBPORT}',
        str(self._dbpath())
    ]
    env = dict(os.environ, PGPASSWORD=_DBPWD)
    subprocess.run(command, check=True, env=env)
except BaseException as e:
    print(e)

I try to run this command in python to restore my postgres database, but it raise FileNotFound error
self._dbpath().exists() is True
and I run this command in cmd, everything is ok.

The key here is the error message. Whatever self._dbpath().exists() returns is not important. What is important is where the error message comes from, and exactly what file it is trying to access.

@OldBoy thanks for reply, it's error only say "FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified', None, 2, None)", and the file is generate by pg_dump, locate in my project directory, What's strange to me is that I can run the whole command successfully in cmd (non-administrator mode), but in python it gives me this error

Note that -U and DBUSER should be two different arguments. Same for -h and localhost, -d and DBNAME, etc.

The other thing you need to do to work without a shell is do a PATH lookup. Instead of just calling pg_restore, use shutil.which('pg_restore'). If the result is None, throw an error that pg_restore isn't on the PATH; otherwise, pass that result as the command name instead of pg_restore itself.

after adding shell=True parameter, it works.
subprocess.run(command, check=True, env=env, shell=True)


The real error is that -h and hostname (and etc for the other options) should be two separate arguments. Passing everything via the shell covers this up, but you should avoid that when you can. See also Actual meaning of shell=True in subprocess

@tripleee, ...half the problem, but that would explain a nonzero exit status from pg_restore or the file not being created; it doesn't explain a FileNotFound direct from subprocess. The other half is that lookup of unqualified executable names on Windows is unnecessarily complex; to avoid that, shutil.which() should be used -- see the "warning" section in https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html starting with: For maximum reliability, use a fully qualified path for the executable and continuing to explain the rationale.

@CashGBL, ...regardless, shell=True is an ugly hack rather than a proper fix -- its behavior is OS-dependent, and it introduces potential security bugs (again, in an OS-specific way). Fix shell=False behavior (by both using shutil.which() to find the executable, and correctly splitting your argument list) and you can have a single version of your code that works on both Windows and UNIXy systems.
